# C Linked List from file not exiting after printing

Tags: c, file, linked-list

So, I have to print a linked list from a file input, which I've managed to get working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Vehicle{
    int option;
    char make [30];
    char model[30]; 
    int car_manufacture_date;
    float maximum_velocity;
    float mass;
    int seats;
    struct Vehicle *next;//linked list node
} vehicle_t;


int main (){

    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("vehicles.crash.txt", "r");

    vehicle_t* first_car = malloc(sizeof(vehicle_t));
    if (first_car == NULL){
        printf("Error. Failed to allocate memory to first_car\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    vehicle_t* current_vehicle = malloc(sizeof(vehicle_t));
    if (current_vehicle == NULL){
        printf("Error. Failed to allocate memory to current_vehicle\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    vehicle_t* new_vehicle = malloc(sizeof(vehicle_t));
    if (new_vehicle == NULL){
        printf("Error. Failed to allocate memory to new_vehicle\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("GOOD1\n");

    current_vehicle = first_car;
    new_vehicle = first_car;
    printf("GOOD2\n");

    //Loading vehicles from file to linked list
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        printf("GOOD3\n");
        while (fscanf(fp,"%d %s %s %d %f %f %d", &new_vehicle->option, new_vehicle->make, new_vehicle->model, &new_vehicle->car_manufacture_date, 
        &new_vehicle->maximum_velocity, &new_vehicle->mass, &new_vehicle->seats) != EOF)
        {
            printf("GOOD4\n");
            current_vehicle->next = new_vehicle;
            current_vehicle = current_vehicle->next;
            new_vehicle = malloc(sizeof(vehicle_t));
            if (first_car == NULL){
                printf("Error. Failed to allocate memory\n");
                new_vehicle->next=NULL;
                exit(1);
            }

            printf("GOOD5\n");
        }
    close(fp);
    printf("Input completed\n");
    }
    else
        printf("Error! couldn't find file\n");

    current_vehicle = first_car;

    while (current_vehicle != NULL) 
    {
        printf("Option: %d\tMake: %s\tModel: %s\tManufactured: %d\tMax Velocity: %.2f\tMass: %.2f\tSeats: %d\n",
        current_vehicle->option, current_vehicle->make, current_vehicle->model, current_vehicle->car_manufacture_date, 
        current_vehicle->maximum_velocity, current_vehicle->mass, current_vehicle->seats);

        new_vehicle = current_vehicle->next;
        current_vehicle = current_vehicle->next;
    };
    printf("Printing completed");
return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine right until the last file item is printed out, after which the program crashes. From what I've seen in other posts, the `while` loop matches them all.

The printed `"GOOD"` statements are just checkpoints

The text in the file is formatted as: 1 Toyota Camry 2010 200.0 1100.0 5

Comment: Have you run your program under a debugger yet?

Comment: Need `current_vehicle->next = NULL;` after input-loop. Also you have many memory leaks.

Comment: Why do you have the first 3 mallocs?  I would have thought you only need to allocate memory for things you have real data for.

Comment: `fclose` should be called instead of `close`, whose arguments are file descriptors rather than `FILE` pointers.

Comment: Enable compiler warnigs, you `close()` is not even declared in your code. It invokes undefined behavior since it treats `FILE *` as an `int`.

Comment: Why no *FMVSS_301_fail* struct member for the crash information `:)`

Comment: Deja vu....  the last version seen didn't have any debugging done either:(

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice I had deleted the 'f' for `fclose`. 

As for the three mallocs, to be quite honest I'm not sure. At this point I was only trying to see what works, and what doesn't. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to set the `->next` field of the last list node to `NULL`. You just called `malloc`, so the value could be anything random, making your printing failed.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the infinite loop was failing to set the final `next` to NULL [as others have mentioned].

But, I think this is easier to see with the code simplified as yours, although mostly correct, was more complicated than it needed to be.

Anyway, this compiles but I didn't test it [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Vehicle {
    int option;
    char make[30];
    char model[30];
    int car_manufacture_date;
    float maximum_velocity;
    float mass;
    int seats;
    struct Vehicle *next;               // linked list node
} vehicle_t;

int
main()
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("vehicles.crash.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error! couldn't find file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    vehicle_t *first_car = NULL;
    vehicle_t *previous_vehicle = NULL;

    // Loading vehicles from file to linked list
    while (1) {
        vehicle_t *new_vehicle = malloc(sizeof(vehicle_t));

        if (new_vehicle == NULL) {
            printf("Error. Failed to allocate memory to new_vehicle\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        // NOTE: the lack of this [in your equivalent code] was the reason
        // for the infinite loop
        new_vehicle->next = NULL;

        if (fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s %d %f %f %d",
            &new_vehicle->option, new_vehicle->make, new_vehicle->model,
            &new_vehicle->car_manufacture_date, &new_vehicle->maximum_velocity,
            &new_vehicle->mass, &new_vehicle->seats) == EOF) {
                free(new_vehicle);
                break;
        }

        if (first_car == NULL)
            first_car = new_vehicle;
        else
            previous_vehicle->next = new_vehicle;

        previous_vehicle = new_vehicle;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    vehicle_t *current_vehicle = first_car;

    while (current_vehicle != NULL) {
        printf("Option: %d\tMake: %s\tModel: %s\tManufactured: %d\tMax Velocity: %.2f\tMass: %.2f\tSeats: %d\n",
            current_vehicle->option, current_vehicle->make,
            current_vehicle->model, current_vehicle->car_manufacture_date,
            current_vehicle->maximum_velocity, current_vehicle->mass,
            current_vehicle->seats);
        current_vehicle = current_vehicle->next;
    };

    printf("Printing completed");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks for the heads up, I'll adjust the answer. Personally, I don't use `*scanf` much, so I just assumed that [simple] part was correct. But, the man page here says that EOF can be returned, so I guess I will have to test it after all.

Comment: @paulsm4 I justed test the program and got -1 (EOF) at end-of-input. So, that matches the linux man page. It is also documented the same way here: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=scanf&sektion=3

Comment: @paulsm4, you are a bit confused `fscanf` returns `EOF` if end of input is reached either before the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. See *man fscanf* under `RETURN VALUE` section.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that code. To be honest I've had a hard time implementing linked lists when physically coding. The concept itself is easy to understand. Also, I haven't found any sort of tutorial that involves populating a linked list from a file, and the questions being asked are a bit too specific for someone relatively new like myself.

Comment: @CraigEstey Actually, do you mind explaining why you've put `while(1)` in there?